# How can I import a lot of components not repeating code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 10-15 components which are imported to `js` file. I must write:

```
import ThreeBlocks from '../components/ThreeBlocks'
```

For **EVERY** component. My components form dynamically so adding same code 
every time when I create new component is tediously.
So if there is some way to avoid repeat code or even use more short writing?

Answer (score 0):

you could make a Lib with all your components on it so you can do import MaxNik,  then use MaxNik.ThreeBlocks,  MaxNik.TwoBlocks

or whatever components you have

Answer (score 0):

You should take this as a warning sign, if each single one of your components depends on so many other components.

That is a strong indicator that your components are too strongly coupled, and you missed a good chance to abstract via a common interface. The code repetition is most likely not only limited to the import statements, but just as much to the usage patterns of the imports as well.

As a bandaid, using an auxiliary component acting as a container/namespace for the commonly used components is possible, but it's not really fixing the design flaw which caused this problem to surface.